# libgdx how to zoom & rotate 3d model on touch

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to create a simple app which allows you to load 3d model from .obj and zoom/rotate it by touching the screen.

I managed to write code which loads 3d model from file and detect gestures but now I am not sure what to do to enable zoom/rotate features by touching the screen.

Here is my code for now:

```
public class RenderObjApp implements ApplicationListener, GestureDetector.GestureListener {
    public static int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    public static int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

    private static final String TAG = RenderObjApp.class.getSimpleName();

    private Mesh model;
    private PerspectiveCamera camera;

    private float scale = 1f;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        model = ObjLoader.loadObj(Gdx.files.internal("data/cessna.obj").read(), true);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }


    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);
        model.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        float aspectRatio = (float) arg0 / (float) arg1;
        camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, 2f * aspectRatio, 2f);
        camera.near = 0.1f;
        camera.translate(0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "touchDown: ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "tap: ");   
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "zoom: ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "fling: ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "pan: ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "zoom: initialDistance=" + initialDistance + ", distance=" + distance);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "pinch: ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

So I am looking how to rotate the PerspectiveCamera and Mesh itself.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on a "Blender-style" camera that has pinch-to-zoom capability as well as (on desktop) most of the functionality you get with Blender's camera. It is a work in progress — it doesn't perfectly imitate the behavior of Blender's camera (yet). I think this will get you pointed in the right direction. Some things you should know:

1. You may have to translate your model so it sits on the origin. The camera remains pointed at the origin unless you translate it. (You can only translate on desktop and not on android so far);
2. I got most of the pinch-to-zoom handling code here: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/PinchToZoom.
3. Sorry for the magic numbers. I will make those constants in the future.
4. If you or anyone else improves this code, I would love if you shared a copy with me.

The Abstract class:

```
/* Author: Christopher Grabowski, yourchristopher6334 gmail.com */

package ...;

import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.GestureListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

abstract public class ControllableCamera extends PerspectiveCamera implements InputProcessor{

    abstract public void resize(int width, int height);
    abstract public void render();

    public ControllableCamera(int fieldOfView, int width, int height) {
        super(fieldOfView, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int direction) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The concrete class:

```
    /* Author: Christopher Grabowski, yourchristopher6334 gmail.com */

package ...;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

/*
 * the pause, resize, and render methods must be called within their corresponding
 * methods in the ApplicationListener
 */

public class BlenderStyleCamera extends ControllableCamera {
    public static final Vector3 ORIGIN = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    private static boolean shiftIsPressed = false, controlIsPressed = false,
            isScrollingUp = false, isScrollingDown = false,
            isSingleTouched = false, justSingleTouched = false;

    private float aspectRatio;
    private int x = -1, y = -1;
    private float dx = 0.0f, dy = 0.0f;
    private final Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();

    // fields related to pinch-to-zoom
    private int numberOfFingers = 0;
    private int fingerOnePointer;
    private int fingerTwoPointer;
    private float lastDistance = 0;
    private final Vector3 fingerOne = new Vector3();
    private final Vector3 fingerTwo = new Vector3();

    public BlenderStyleCamera(int fieldOfView, int width, int height) {
        super(fieldOfView, width, height);
        aspectRatio = viewportHeight / viewportWidth;
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        up.set(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        position.set(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f);
        far = 300.0f;
        lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.1f);
        lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        update();
    }

    public void pause() {
        numberOfFingers = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewportWidth = width;
        viewportHeight = height;
        aspectRatio = viewportHeight / viewportWidth;
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        if (isSingleTouched) {

            // This gets the change in touch position and
            // compensates for the aspect ratio.
            if (x == -1 || y == -1 || justSingleTouched) {
                x = Gdx.input.getX();
                y = Gdx.input.getY();
            } else {
                dx = (x - Gdx.input.getX());
                dy = (y - Gdx.input.getY()) / aspectRatio;
            }

            // This zooms when control is pressed.
            if (controlIsPressed && dy > 0) {
                scrollIn();
            } else if (controlIsPressed && dy < 0) {
                scrollOut();
            }

            // This translates the camera blender-style
            // if shift is pressed.
            // Note that this will look weird with a
            // perspective camera.
            else if (shiftIsPressed) {
                translateTangentially();
            }

            // Default is to rotate the object
            // (actually rotate the camera about a sphere
            // that surrounds the object).
            else {
                travelAround();
            }

            x = Gdx.input.getX();
            y = Gdx.input.getY();

            justSingleTouched = false;
        }

        // this zooms when the mouse wheel is rotated
        if (isScrollingUp) {
            scrollIn();
            isScrollingUp = false;
        } else if (isScrollingDown) {
            scrollOut();
            isScrollingDown = false;
        }

        // Some key controls
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
            translateTangentially(1, 0);
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)
                || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
            translateTangentially(-1, 0);
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            translateTangentially(0, 1);
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)
                || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
            translateTangentially(0, -1);
        }

        update();
    }

    // These methods create the pinch zoom
    // and set some flags for logic in render method.
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        // for pinch-to-zoom
        numberOfFingers++;
        if (numberOfFingers == 1) {
            isSingleTouched = true;
            justSingleTouched = true;
            fingerOnePointer = pointer;
            fingerOne.set(x, y, 0);
        } else if (numberOfFingers == 2) {
            isSingleTouched = false;
            fingerTwoPointer = pointer;
            fingerTwo.set(x, y, 0);

            float distance = fingerOne.dst(fingerTwo);
            lastDistance = distance;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer) {
        if (numberOfFingers > 1) {
            if (pointer == fingerOnePointer) {
                fingerOne.set(x, y, 0);
            }
            if (pointer == fingerTwoPointer) {
                fingerTwo.set(x, y, 0);
            }

            float distance = fingerOne.dst(fingerTwo);

            if (lastDistance > distance) {
                scrollOut();
            } else if (lastDistance < distance) {
                scrollIn();
            }

            lastDistance = distance;
            update();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        isSingleTouched = false;
        if (numberOfFingers == 1) {
            Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            unproject(touchPoint);
        }
        numberOfFingers--;

        // just some error prevention... clamping number of fingers (ouch! :-)
        if (numberOfFingers < 0) {
            numberOfFingers = 0;
        }

        lastDistance = 0;
        return false;
    }   

    // These methods set flags for logic in render method.
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

        switch (keycode) {
        case (Keys.SHIFT_LEFT):
        case (Keys.SHIFT_RIGHT):
            shiftIsPressed = true;
            break;
        case (Keys.CONTROL_LEFT):
        case (Keys.CONTROL_RIGHT):
            controlIsPressed = true;
            break;
        case (Keys.O):
            this.up.set(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            this.position.set(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f);
            this.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
            this.update();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int arg0) {
        shiftIsPressed = controlIsPressed = false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int direction) {
        if (direction == -1) {
            isScrollingUp = true;
        } else if (direction == 1) {
            isScrollingDown = true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // The rest of the methods translate the camera.
    public void scrollIn() {
        float magnitude = 1.0f;
        scrollIn(magnitude);
    }

    public void scrollIn(float magnitude) {
        if (position.dst2(ORIGIN) > 2.0f) {
            tmp.set(position);
            tmp.nor();
            this.translate(-tmp.x * magnitude, -tmp.y * magnitude, -tmp.z
                    * magnitude);
            update();
        }
    }

    public void scrollOut() {
        float magnitude = 1.0f;
        scrollOut(magnitude);
    }

    public void scrollOut(float magnitude) {
        tmp.set(position);
        tmp.nor();
        this.translate(tmp.x * magnitude, tmp.y * magnitude, tmp.z * magnitude);
        update();
    }

    private void travelAround() {
        tmp.set(up);
        rotateAround(ORIGIN, tmp, dx);
        tmp.crs(position).nor();
        rotateAround(ORIGIN, tmp, dy);
    }

    private void translateTangentially() {
        translateTangentially(dx, dy);
    }

    private void translateTangentially(float dx, float dy) {
        tmp.set(up);
        tmp.crs(position);
        if (dx > 0) {
            translate(tmp.x / 15.0f, tmp.y / 15.0f, tmp.z / 15.0f);
        } else if (dx < 0) {
            translate(-tmp.x / 15.0f, -tmp.y / 15.0f, -tmp.z / 15.0f);
        }

        if (dy > 0) {
            translate(-up.x, -up.y, -up.z);
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            translate(up);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this: [Mesh rendering issue libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927277/mesh-rendering-issue-libgdx).

Method **render** contains the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to rotate the camera, or rotate the model.

I believe the libGDX [Camera.rotateAround](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html) method does what you need.  Leave the "point" as the center of your model and set the "axis" parameter based on which way the user is flinging/panning.  The "angle" can either be a fixed value, or relative to the intensity of the fling/pan.